# In which version of C# Indexers were introduced?

Tags: c#, .net

In which version of C# or .Net Framework Indexers were introduced ?

Comment: @GiladGreen: To be fair, docs on historical knowledge like that are *relatively* hard to find.

Comment: [C# language specification v1.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/e/a9e229b9-fee5-4c3e-8476-917dee385062/csharp%20language%20specification%20v1.0.doc).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

They've always been in C# and .NET, right from [version 1.0](http://download.microsoft.com/download/a/9/e/a9e229b9-fee5-4c3e-8476-917dee385062/csharp%20language%20specification%20v1.0.doc).